# Delay data loading until animation completes in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'd like to know what the best approach is to delay the loading of my model data till after an animation has completed.

In my application I'm listening to changes to the route. Then, when a certain route is matched, I open a panel with an animation. But I'd like the loading of the data to start after the animation completed.

Here's how I listen to the route:

```
App.ApplicationController.reopen({
  currentPathChanged:function() {
    App.panelView.setNeedsOpen(this.get('currentPath') == 'index' ? false : true);
  }.observes('currentPath')
});
```

And this is one of the routes that is called when the panel has to open:

```
App.NewsitemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Newsitem.find();
  }
});
```

But as you can see, the data gets preloaded when the animation is still running. How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would not at all delay loading itself as you should use this precious time to load data in background and 'distract' the user with the animation.
So why are you not showing the animation but load the data in parallel and as soon as the animation is finished you remove the corresponding dom revealing the rendered data?